# How to change second-order tensor components when switching from right-hand to left-hand coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensors

I have second-order tensor defined in left-hand coordinate system. Now I need to use it in right-hand coordinate system. For simplicity, say it is Z-coordinate which is flipped.

For vectors (first-order tensor) it is obvious:

if

$$\overrightarrow {\mathbf V}_{LH}=[V_x, V_y, V_z]$$

then

$$\overrightarrow {\mathbf V}_{RH}=[V_x, V_y, -V_z]$$

How it will work for second-order tensor though? Assuming

$$
  \mathbf T_{LH}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
              T_{xx} & T_{xy} & T_{xz} \\
              T_{yx} & T_{yy} & T_{yz} \\
              T_{zx} & T_{zy} & T_{zz} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

then

$$
  \mathbf T_{RH}= ?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is know that any rank two tensor change as $B^{\top}TB$ for a base change $B$.
In your case the matrix for $B$ is 
\begin{bmatrix}
              1 & 0 & 0 \\
              0 & 1 & 0 \\
              0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
So for $B^{\top}TB$ you are going to get

\begin{bmatrix}
              T_{xx} & T_{xy} & -T_{xz} \\
              T_{yx} & T_{yy} & -T_{yz} \\
              -T_{zx} & -T_{zy} & T_{zz} \\
  \end{bmatrix}

You need to think that, in general, the components are related via $\vec V_{RH}=B^{-1}\vec V_{LH}$.